# Is there a way to auto resize the CentralPanel of egui(0.21.0)?

Tags: rust, egui, eframe

I am very new to Egui and gui making and am trying to make a application for windows, but I wanted to auto resize the CentralPanel according to the ui widgets inside of that panel, is there a way to do that? (If I am not able to resize the central panel then is there any other way to make the program window to auto resize to just fit the widgets and other ui things) Also, I was wondering is there a way to give ID to the CentralPanel or any other panel in the latest version of egui(0.21.0).
psa: also I am using eframe.

I tried reading about egui(0.21.0) in docs.rs but I was not able to find any method which can help me to solve the problem.